# Parse Eloquent Model in Blade as JSON

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to use "Vue.js" to display data in my views and update it's content while adding new items or deleting them. In other hand, I'm retrieving original data as an eloquent model in my blade's views (because I need some data to be displayed in other parts of my page and accesing it through eloquent relationship's methods).

I know that the common aproach is to make a Rest WebService that returns the data as JSON encoded data, but in my point of view it is a waste of resources because I will do multiple calls to retrieve the same data in another format.

Is there a way to parse my eloquent model data into a "script" tag inside my blade template as JSON so that I can read it with Vue.js? Which will be the method that you recommend?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

convert the stdclassobject to json type in controller and then send it to Vue js it and then render the view